# Including child Objects in Entityframework

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, iqueryable

I want to include child objects on an IQueryable list..

I want to include a child object on selected columns of some table type IQueryable list..

I tried like this:

```
IQueryable<Persons> persons = Context.Persons.Select(x=> new persons{Pkid=x.pkid, FirstName=x.FirstName}).AsQueryable();

persons= persons.Include("Address");
```

this include of child objects is not working..anyone please help...where I am doing wrong..
thanks alot...

Answer (score 3):

`Include` doesn't work with projection. Moreover it is not needed. Just do this:

```
var query = context.Persons
                   .Select(x => new PersonDto
                       {
                          Id = x.pkid, 
                          FirstName = x.FirstName,
                          Address = x.Address
                       });
```

Few points here:

- No `Include`
- `Address` accessed directly in projection, EF will handle this
- I'm using `PersonDto` as target of projection. `PersonDto` has just `Id`, `FirstName` and `Address`.
- You can project to custom type or anonymous type but you cannot project to entity type (the mapped type) - it doesn't work and it throws exception.
- If you want to use mapped type you can't return only selected scalar columns - all columns will always be loaded. Only navigation properties can be loaded selectively. To overcome this people sometimes use [Table splitting](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/ef-table-splitting-ndash-the-opposite-of-entity-splitting/) but that is something which works if you can divide your big entity into disjunct entities. In your scenario use just projection.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `Include()` on a projection, try this:

```
Iquerable<Persons> persons = Context.Persons
                                    .Include("Address")
                                    .Select(x=> new persons{Pkid=x.pkid, FirstName=x.FirstName})
                                    .AsQuerable();
```

Also you have a naming conflict, you project to a type `persons` and want to hold the results in an `IQueryable` named `persons` - one of them is wrong. Is there a reason you need the projection at all? You could just do

```
Iquerable<Persons> persons = Context.Persons.Include("Address");
```

Comment: its just a sample..thats why i use persons in both places..sorry for that mistake..i need to do project and need pick only few number of columns..becoz in my project i have to do an include on one of my table which has 100 columns..it is taking too much time to excute (.ToList()) on that results...more over i will use only 5 columns from that results..i don't need those 95 columns in that table..I can't change the DB structure and its 5 year old database..Can I do an include on projected result...thansk for your reply...

Comment: @Sunny: No you cannot do an `Include()` on the projected result, but both the `Select()` and the `Include()` operate on the DB so above suggested changes should work for you, it will result in a SQL query that only selected the columns you need.

Comment: @Sunny: BrokenGlass is saying just what i was saying in my post. Also the sample BrokenGlass posted is OK. Just add what ever columns you like from Address entity to projected object.

Comment: Thanks for your answers..but I am getting this error The entity or complex type 'tablename' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query..I always getting this error when ever I do a select (new table type..) on the results..

Comment: @Sunny: you shouldn't *project* to an entity you have to either project to an anonymous type or a custom POCO class that only contains the properties you want.

Comment: so I have to create a custom class...hmm...so entity frame work doesn't have capability to project to some table table type..so I have to create list<objects> in the custom class to get the child objects right...anyway thanks a lot for your suggestion..I will try with the custom classes...

Answer (score 2):

First: Check if **lazy loading** is enabled or not. I experienced different results when it was enabled. I prefer lazy loading being disabled.

Second: Check this syntax:

```
result = (From person In context.Persons.Include("Address")).ToList();
```

*P.S.*: Useful EF Tips & Tricks : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/03/26/index-of-tips.aspx

**UPDATE:**

Include is not working, because your are using it on newly created objects, not the objects available in the context. you should use Include before creating new objects.

Check This:

```
result = (From person In context.Persons.Include("Address") Select New With {.FirstName = item.FirstName, .AddressValue = item.Address.Value}).ToList();
```

Comment: I want to do an include on projected result..I don't want to get all columns in my table..i do have table which has too many columns(like 100)..and .ToList() taking too much time to process all those results..thanks for ur reply..

Comment: @Sunny: Please check the update I've added to my post and comment back how it worked.